# Anime about a boy fighting robots in space

Tags: story-identification, anime

I'd like to identify this anime which I watched around 15 years ago. It looks like a Japanese anime, but I'm not sure.

I do not remember a lot about this anime. I only remember there is a boy fighting robots in space. The setting is quite futuristic with a spaceship that shoots lasers, drones, robots etc. There is a weapon that looks like a lightsaber in the anime. Most character in the anime use the lightsaber, but the main character which is a boy prefer to use an magical iron sword. The iron sword able to cut metal easily.

I'm not sure about this and perhaps it's another anime. The bad guys is a bald guy with a something like a half moon sword and has black armor.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a mecha series. Do you recall what the boy looked like? Was he piloting another 'robot' or just fighting them himself?

Comment: I'm afraid that's all I remember. The only scene I remember is the boy slash a metal door like it was made from a butter

Answer (score 2):

I remember an anime with mecha and a boy using a sword/saber:

[*Lost universe*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1184/Lost_Universe?q=lost%20universe)

> Millie Nocturne has one great goal in life: to be the best in the universe - at absolutely everything! But when she tries her hand at being the "best detective," she ends up an unwilling partner with two people who will change her life forever: Kane Blueriver, the psi-blade-wielding master of the starship Swordbreaker, and Canal, the smart-mouthed holographic image of the ship's computer.
>
> Join this unlikely trio on their adventures as they hurtle through space facing off against intergalactic crime lords, rogue starships, and hijackers dressed as chickens... and that's just the tip of the asteroid!

[image: Lost Universe poster]

Answer (score 0):

The other one that I've watched that this could be is:

[*Shin Hakkenden*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/1823/Shin_Hakkenden?q=Shin%20hakk)

> Taking place in the future, during this time wars were occuring in
>   heaven, mostly for possession between the eight moons created by the
>   savior Fuse that surrounded God's land. When the war ended, there was
>   only one ruling family - that of the Oowaris, and the remaining son
>   gained control of all the moons of heaven, except for one. Meiten, the
>   moon of the pope, where people refrained from war and were therefore
>   out of it's terms.
>
> Eight people. Each from one of the eight moons. Each possessing one of
>   the jewels - the elements that compose Earth. They are those who are
>   destined to become saviors of humanity. All of them have sacrificed
>   for these jewels, and are determined to complete their duty to Queen
>   Fuse who entrusted these to them. When the mad emperor Kai threatens
>   to revive a ghost who wants to prevent the restoration of Earth, these
>   eight must battle using the powers given by their jewels in order to
>   create Earth and defeat those who want to prevent it.
>
> So they all go to Kusanagi, the ship in the center of God's land. They
>   must gather the jewels in the key called Yatsufusa at Kusanagi's
>   center, in order to create Earth.

[image: Shin Hakkenden poster]